# running zeppelin-solidity demos shows undefined return message

Tags: truffle

I'm studying deploying smart contract following the steps on [this article](https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6).

I used absolute path for import instead of relative path because compiler was not able to look into import files in node_modules so it compiles

the truffle migrate seems good because when I input `JCoinCrowdsale.deployed()` it returns full info (I named JCoin for this example)

but when I input `JCoinCrowdsale.deployed().then(inst => { crowdsale = inst })` , it returns undefined

[image]

Any clue on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it correctly! And I see that you assign the result of the promise `JCoinCrowdsale.deployed()` to the variable `crowdsale`.

The reason it shows `undefined` is due to the fact that this function `inst => { crowdsale = inst }` does not explicitly `return` anything.

If you type `crowdsale` on to the truffle console you will be able to see the same JavaScript object you get when you just type `JCoinCrowdsale.deployed()`.

Hope it helps and wish you all the best in your learning :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it goes well through to the end of your tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:
var crowdsale = JCoinCrowdsale.deployed().then(function(inst) { crowdsale = inst })

Comment: thanks, this is not a problem anymore. the object is assigned to var crowdsale in the sample code, the assign itself does not return anything so it's showing undefined